# How to get multiple google maps on 1 page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the code from [this](http://codepen.io/eatrero/pen/cIKEd) codepen which I get to work fine but I have multiple google maps I need on one page, I thought I could just copy/paste the code just with a different address and target a different div but this doesn't work...any ideas on how I can do this using this code?

This is javascript I have now:

```
    jQuery(function($) {

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "The Hop Exchange, 24 Southwark Street, London, SE1 1TY"; //Add your address here, all on one line.
addresses = ["The Hop Exchange, 24 Southwark Street, London, SE1 1TY"];

var latitude;
var longitude;
var color = "#e2a99b"; //Set your tint color. Needs to be a hex value.

function getGeocode() {
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng(); 
      initGoogleMap();
      } 
  });
}

function initGoogleMap() {
  var styles = [
      {
        stylers: [
          { saturation: -100 }
        ]
      }
  ];

  var options = {
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['Styled']
    },
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    zoom: 17,
    scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    disableDefaultUI: true, 
    mapTypeId: 'Styled'
  };
  var div = document.getElementById('googleMap');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(div, options);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map:map,
      draggable:false,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude)
  });
  var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Styled' });
  map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<div class='iwContent'>"+address+"</div>"
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      window.location = "#";
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });


  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-84.999999, -179.999999), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(84.999999, 179.999999));

  rect = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      bounds: bounds,
      fillColor: color,
      fillOpacity: 0.5,
      strokeWeight: 0,
      map: map
  });

  var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() { 
    $('#map-banner').show();
    $("#map-header").fitText(1.2, { minFontSize: '20px', maxFontSize: '400px'});
    google.maps.event.removeListener(listener); 
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', getGeocode);

});
```

and my html is:

```
    <div id="map-banner" style="display:none">

</div>

<div id="googleMap">

</div>
```

Comment: What you have now works, and doesn't have anything to do with multiple maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to get multiple maps, loop over the addresses array in the `getGeoCode` function, and call the `initGoogleMap` function passing in a div, address and coordinates. See amended codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWGrMQ

Comment: Thankyou, that is brilliant, I now have my multiple maps up and running but just wondering how I would have a different overlay tint for each one? this is why I chose that code in the first place because I could have an overlay tint on my maps...thankyou for your help

Comment: Change the colour in the loop and pass that into the `initGoogleMap` function too?

Comment: thankyou for your reply but I'm not a javascript developer...I have tried adding var color = ["#85cad1","#ccc","#666","#333"]; and then adding it to the initGoogleMap like this... initGoogleMap(document.querySelector('#googleMap' + i), latitude, longitude, address, color);

Comment: Define the color array where the addresses array is defined, and pass it to the function as color[i] and then it will work.

Comment: Hi, just come up against another issue...how would I have multiple colored markers the same color as the maps?